# Grant user access to limited number of tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm running some tests and I'm trying to see if I can create a user with access to only 1 or 2 tables in my db. Does anyone know how this is done? My code below fails:

```
GRANT SELECT ON testdb.fruits, testdb.sports TO joe@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

The error says I have an error in my syntax.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Run them as two individual `GRANT` statements:

```
GRANT SELECT ON testdb.fruits TO joe@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
GRANT SELECT ON testdb.sports TO joe@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

[The MySQL GRANT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html) only permits one object in the `priv_level` position:, though it may use a `*` as a wildcard:

```
GRANT
    priv_type [(column_list)]
      [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
    ON [object_type] priv_level
    TO user_specification [, user_specification] ...
    [REQUIRE {NONE | ssl_option [[AND] ssl_option] ...}]
    [WITH with_option ...]

object_type:
    TABLE
  | FUNCTION
  | PROCEDURE

priv_level:
    *
  | *.*
  | db_name.*
  | db_name.tbl_name
  | tbl_name
  | db_name.routine_name
```

**The part below does not appear to work on MySQL 5.5**. [How to "subtract" privileges in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131849/how-to-subtract-privileges-in-mysql) addresses why.

<strike>To grant `SELECT` on all tables then selectively revoke, you could do:</strike>

```
GRANT SELECT ON testdb.* TO joe@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.tblname FROM joe@localhost;
```

This seems to be an odd method though, and I think I would individually GRANT rather than individually REVOKE.

Comment: Interesting. Can MySQL also remove access to specific tables? That way I can assign `testdb.*` then just remove accesss to the tables I don't want them accessing.

Comment: @enchance Yes, see addition above.

Comment: GRANT SELECT ON testdb.* TO joe@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.tblname FROM joe@localhost;
The revoke statement will not work. It will give the following error
"There is no such grant defined for user 'joe' on host 'localhost' on table 'tblname'"

Comment: @Rahul Indeed, I cannot make it work either with MariaDB 5.5. I wonder if this worked correctly back in 2011, when I would probably have tested it on 5.0, and no one has commented before that it doesn't work. I'm going to add a note above, and link to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131849/how-to-subtract-privileges-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [mysql.tables_priv table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant-tables.html) directly:

```
INSERT INTO mysql.tables_priv (`Host`, `Db`, `User`, `Table_name`, `Grantor`, `Table_priv`)
VALUES
('%', DATABASE(), 'someuser', 'mytable1', CURRENT_USER, 'Select,Insert,Update,Delete'),
('%', DATABASE(), 'someuser', 'mytable2', CURRENT_USER, 'Select,Insert,Update,Delete')
```

After a manual update to these tables, you will need to explicitly run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` query to tell MySQL to update its permissions cache (not required when using `GRANT`)