# MySQL grant select to all columns in table except one column

Tags: mysql

It is possible to grant select all columns in table except one for user?
I tried to search any way to do this and read some docs, but can`t find solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to "subtract" privileges in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131849/how-to-subtract-privileges-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

For example, you want to grant update privilege on ename column only, then give the following statement (where xyz is the username)

grant update (ename) on emp to xyz;

Comment: What if i want to grant update privilege to all columns except ename?

Answer (score 0):

You have to name all the other columns, which could be tedious if it is a large table.

```
GRANT SELECT(col1,...,col99)
ON table_name
TO user_name
```